# Why sorting a Linked List is not working?

Tags: javascript, sorting, linked-list

I have a linked list which is in unsorted order. The problem is that I want to sort the given linked list without the use of `Merge Sort` algorithm. My basic approach written in code is given below:

```js
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * function ListNode(val, next) {
 *     this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
 *     this.next = (next===undefined ? null : next)
 * }
 */
/**
 * @param {ListNode} head
 * @return {ListNode}
 */
 
// head = -1 -> 5 -> 3 -> 4 -> 0
 
var sortList = function(head) {
    if(head === null){
        return null;
    }
    if(head.next === null){
        return head;
    }
    
    sortList(head.next);
    return sortingList(head);
};

function sortingList(head){
    let temp = head;
    let prev = head;
    let curr = head.next;
    while(curr !== null){
        if(temp.val < curr.val){
            break;
        }else{
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr.next;
        }
    }
    if(temp.val > prev.val){
        let temp_list = temp.next;
        temp.next = null;
        let prev_list = prev.next;
        prev.next = temp;
        temp.next = prev_list;
        head = temp_list;
    }
    return head;
}

let head = {
  val: -1,
  next: {
    val: 5,
    next: {
      val: 3,
      next: {
        val: 4,
        next: {
          val: 0,
          next: null
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(sortList(head));
```

I have checked many times that when we call `sortingList`, then It wants to give the desired output but don't know why `head` is not being updated that point. That's why linked list is loosing many items or nodes.

Expected output should be: -1 -> 0 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5

Comment: Your algorithm is flawed.  For 5 entries, you'll recursively call yourself 5 times.  You then call `sortingList`, which sorts its input and returns the new head.  You then return that from `sortList`, BUT you never use the value returned by the deeper calls to `sortList`.  Thus, you're switching the pointers, but you have the wrong sub-heads.

Comment: Then what changes should I need to make to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

- In `sortList` a recursive call is made to sort the rest of the list (after the first node), but although the potentially new head of that sorted sublist is returned, the caller ignores this value. And so `head.next` is not modified while sometimes it should have.
- In `sortingList` the `if` condition after the loop -- that checks whether the `temp` node (the head node) should be moved -- is wrong. For instance, if in your example input you would change `val: 3` to `val: 4` (creating a duplicate value), the problem becomes apparent. That `if` condition should check whether the `prev` node reference was moved in the loop. Only if that is true, the node-move operation should be executed.

Here is your code with those two lines of code corrected:

```js
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * function ListNode(val, next) {
 *     this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
 *     this.next = (next===undefined ? null : next)
 * }
 */
/**
 * @param {ListNode} head
 * @return {ListNode}
 */
 
// head = -1 -> 5 -> 3 -> 4 -> 0
 
var sortList = function(head) {
    if(head === null){
        return null;
    }
    if(head.next === null){
        return head;
    }
    
    head.next = sortList(head.next); // Corrected
    return sortingList(head);
};

function sortingList(head){
    let temp = head;
    let prev = head;
    let curr = head.next;
    while(curr !== null){
        if(temp.val < curr.val){
            break;
        }else{
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr.next;
        }
    }
    if(prev !== head){ // Corrected
        let temp_list = temp.next;
        temp.next = null;
        let prev_list = prev.next;
        prev.next = temp;
        temp.next = prev_list;
        head = temp_list;
    }
    return head;
}

let head = {
  val: -1,
  next: {
    val: 5,
    next: {
      val: 3,
      next: {
        val: 4,
        next: {
          val: 0,
          next: null
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(sortList(head));
```